# Adding images In SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, database

Hi i have to add a image path to a column in table. i have the image file in a local folder. how to achieve this? i dont want to add the image fully as binary , i just want to add the image path to the column. thanx in advance.

Comment: use varchar as field type, get the relative/absolute path and store it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save it as a `VARCHAR(260)` and then you can access it from whatever program you are using/writing. [edited due to marc_s' comment]

Comment: Since a path in Windows can be a maximum of 260 characters long - `varchar(max)` with a maximum of **2 GByte** of data seems like a massive overkill..... `varchar(260)` would be **just as good** and doesn't carry any of the downsides of the `max` datatypes...

Comment: I couldn't remember the max length of the address =)